# Power BI extract filename from path in table

Tags: powerbi

In Power BI does anyone have any idea how I can extract a filename from a path in a table column without using SQL?  DAX does not seem to have reverse searches. Also please note that some file names do not have paths.

In SQL I could achieve this with the following:

```sql
CASE
        WHEN @FullPath = 'TRUE' OR CHARINDEX('\', dbo.Usage.App) = 0 THEN 
          UPPER(dbo.Usage.App)
        ELSE
          UPPER (RIGHT(dbo.Usage.App, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(dbo.Usage.App)) -1))
    END
    AS AppName
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your fullpath is in Column1, I believe this DAX based solution would work:

Create a new column with...

`=RIGHT([Column1],LEN([Column1])-SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE([Column1],"\","@",LEN([Column1])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE([Column1],"\","")))))`

I found this solution [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/General/30895.html).

Here's a screenclip that might help too:

[image]

*Be sure to replace Column1 with the name of your column.*

Comment: keeps telling me problems with the search parameter invalid parameters.

Comment: I added a screenclip and final note to be sure to replace Column1 with your column name. Be sure to replace every instance of Column1.

Comment: Column = RIGHT([App],LEN([App])-SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE([App],"\","@",LEN([App])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE([App],"\",""))))) Gives error and argument of 'SUBSTITUTE' has the wrong data type of has an invalid value  I wonder if its because some filenames do not have a path?

Comment: Fixed with if(SEARCH("\", [App],1,-1)=-1, [App], RIGHT([App],LEN([App])-SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE([App],"\","@",LEN([App])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE([App],"\",""))))))

Comment: Great! So it was that there was no path preceding the file name, right?

Comment: yes that one threw it, nice answer tho, would be so much simpler with a reverse search

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
if(SEARCH("\", [App],1,-1)=-1, [App], RIGHT([App],LEN([App])-SEARCH("@",SUBSTITUTE([App],"\","@",LEN([App])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE([App],"\",""))))))
```